Dynamically remove the numbers from the end of a varchar in SQL
AccountId        LoginId
1                Tata-Motors\Harry9  
2                Orian-Analytics\Kartik10  
3                adventure-works\Rajashree3

I am working on Microsoft SQL Server 2022 - 16.0.1115.1
I have this kind of sample data I created for this experiment.
I want to remove the company name from the front and the numbers from the back dynamically.
I have figured out removing the company name quite easily but I am struggling with dynamically removing the number from the end such that the program works regardless of the length of the number.
Create statement:
CREATE TABLE Tester(
    [BusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LoginID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL
)

Insert Statement:
insert into dbo.Tester(BusinessEntityID, LoginId)
values
(1, 'Tata-Motors\Harry9'),
(2, 'Orian-Analytics\Kartik10'),
(3,'adventure-works\Darshana3')

I tried PatIndex but I don't seem to be able to figure out the exact formula to solve this problem.
select LoginId,
    Substring(LoginId,
    charindex('\', LoginID)+1, LEN(LoginID)-charindex('\', LoginID)-patindex('%[0-9]%',LoginId)) Name
from dbo.Tester

This is what I have come up with so far but it is giving an error

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Expected Output:
LoginId                     Name
Tata-Motors\Harry9          Harry
Orian-Analytics\Kartik10    Kartik
adventure-works\Rajashree3  Rajashree


which version of SQL server are you using?

SSMS is just an IDE (like) application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

That'll leave the digits, @PowerMouse .

Telling us you use ssms is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dashboard radio.

It might be better to put the Error in the Question title cause that will make it easier for others to search in the future.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

This was the length adjustment you needed: patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(LoginID)) - 1

I believe you meant to write patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(LoginID)) + 1 @shawnt00

Well that expression is the actual length of the end sequence. When you subtract and distribute the minus sign, yes, it does become a plus one.

A minimal reproducible example is not provided.
I am assuming it is SQL Server 2022.
In SQL Server 2022, an enhancement is available in the TRIM() function. This enhancement allows to remove any specific character(s) from one of the sides (left, right) or both sides of the column \ expression along with the space character char(32).
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (AccountId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, LoginId VARCHAR(128));
INSERT @tbl (LoginId) VALUES
('Tata-Motors\Harry9'),
('Orian-Analytics\Kartik10'),
('adventure-works\Rajashree3');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
SELECT * 
    , TRIM(TRAILING '1234567890' FROM RIGHT(LoginId, LEN(LoginId) - CHARINDEX('\', LoginId + '\'))) AS [name]
FROM @tbl;

-- Method #2
SELECT * 
    , TRIM(TRAILING '1234567890' FROM PARSENAME(REPLACE(LoginId,'\','.'), 1)) AS [name]
FROM @tbl;

Output



AccountId
LoginId
name




1
Tata-Motors\Harry9
Harry


2
Orian-Analytics\Kartik10
Kartik


3
adventure-works\Rajashree3
Rajashree




Assuming you are on SQL Server 2022 (or Azure SQL Database) you can use CHARINDEX to find the position of the backslash (\) and then STUFF to remove the characters up to that position. Then you can use RTRIM to remove the digits from the right, as it now accepts characters to remove as a second parameter:
SELECT RTRIM(STUFF(V.LoginID,1,CHARINDEX('\',V.LoginID),N''),'0123456789')
FROM (VALUES(1,N'Tata-Motors\Harry9'),
            (2,N'Orian-Analytics\Kartik10'),
            (3,N'adventure-works\Rajashree3'))V(AccountID,LoginID);


This is a recent solution for this:
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(YourField, '1234567890', '##########'),'#','')


need to remove company name

@PowerMouse: There is no need to remove that (see title: "I want to dynamically remove the numbers from the end of a varchar in SQL" )

This would remove any digits from the middle of the string. While it doesn't appear that OP has this issue nevertheless it doesn't strictly remove from the right as the problem is described so it's worth noting.

WITH 
T AS 
(SELECT * 
 FROM (VALUES (1, N'Tata-Motors\Harry9'),
      (2, N'Orian-Analytics\Kartik10'),
      (3, N'adventure-works\Rajashree3')) AS V (AccountID, LoginID)
)
SELECT TRANSLATE(RIGHT(LoginID, LEN(LoginID) - CHARINDEX('\', LoginID)), '0123456789', '          ')
FROM   T


This SQL query dynamically trims the leading company name and trailing numbers from the LoginId field to extract the username.
SELECT 
    LoginId,
    SUBSTRING(
        LoginId,
        CHARINDEX('\', LoginId) + 1,
        LEN(LoginId) - CHARINDEX('\', LoginId) - 
        (LEN(LoginId) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(LoginId)))
    ) AS Name
FROM dbo.Tester;




    Tata-Motors\Harry9          Harry
    Orian-Analytics\Kartik10    Kartik
    adventure-works\Rajashree3  Rajashree


See another example
select id,LoginId 
  ,substring(part1_2,1,charindex('\',part1_2)-1) part_1
  ,substring(part1_2,charindex('\',part1_2)+1,100) part_2
  ,part_3,part1_2
from(
select *
  ,substring(LoginId,1,len(LoginId)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(LoginId))+1)part1_2
  ,right(LoginId,patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(LoginId))-1) part_3
from test
)a

Test data



id
LoginId
part_1
part_2
part_3
part1_2




1
Tata-Motors\Harry9
Tata-Motors
Harry
9
Tata-Motors\Harry


2
Orian-Analytics\Kartik10
Orian-Analytics
Kartik
10
Orian-Analytics\Kartik


3
adventure-works\Rajashree3
adventure-works
Rajashree
3
adventure-works\Rajashree


4
Team24\include324
Team24
include
324
Team24\include


5
Team24\nonum
Team24
nonum

Team24\nonum


6
Alpha\nonum
Alpha
nonum

Alpha\nonum



Fiddle
